# Como deixar um programa em loop esperando sempre um novo INPUT, mesmo após lançamento de uma exceção?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loop

Fiz um programa para realizar sorteios, entretanto não consigo deixá-lo em loop aguardando um novo input após um erro na entrada. Ex:

```
from random import sample
from excecoes import SorteioInvalido


class Sorteador:
    def __init__(self, num_sorteados):
        self._num_sorteados = num_sorteados
        self._participantes = self.carrega_participantes()
        self._lista_sorteados = self.carrega_lista_sorteados()
        self.current_index = 0

@property
def num_sorteados(self):
    return self._num_sorteados

@property
def participantes(self):
    return self._participantes

def __iter__(self):
    return self

def __next__(self):
    indice_final = len(self._lista_sorteados)
    if self.current_index >= indice_final:
        raise StopIteration
    current = self._lista_sorteados[self.current_index]
    self.current_index += 1
    return current

def carrega_participantes(self):
    participantes = []
    with open('participantes.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as arquivo:
        for linha in arquivo:
            linha = linha.strip()
            participantes.append(linha)
    arquivo.close()
    return participantes

def carrega_lista_sorteados(self):
    if self.validando_num_participantes():
        lista_sorteados = sample(
            sample(self.participantes, len(self.participantes)), self.num_sorteados)
        return lista_sorteados

def validando_num_participantes(self):
    if len(self.participantes) >= self.num_sorteados:
        return True
    raise SorteioInvalido(
        'Registre um número de pessoas a serem sorteadas que seja menor ou igual ao número de participantes')

while True:
        num_sorteados = int(input('Quantos premiados devem ser sorteados? '))
        sorteia = Sorteador(num_sorteados)
        for sorteado in sorteia:
            print(sorteado)
```

Selecionando 3 como input, o programa irá retornar:

```
Paulo
Francisco
Matheus
```

mas,**como minha lista de participantes tem 10 nomes, se eu digitar 12 no input irá cair na exceção de validação de números de participantes**, no qual precisa ser um número maior ou igual ao número de sorteios a serem realizados, retornando:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\mfsra\Desktop\Projetos\Sorteador\sorteador.py", line 5, in <module>
    sorteia = Sorteador(num_sorteados)
  File "c:\Users\mfsra\Desktop\Projetos\Sorteador\src.py", line 9, in __init__
    self._lista_sorteados = self.carrega_lista_sorteados()
  File "c:\Users\mfsra\Desktop\Projetos\Sorteador\src.py", line 41, in carrega_lista_sorteados
    if self.validando_num_participantes():
  File "c:\Users\mfsra\Desktop\Projetos\Sorteador\src.py", line 49, in validando_num_participantes
    raise SorteioInvalido(
excecoes.SorteioInvalido: Registre um número de pessoas a serem sorteadas que seja menor ou igual ao número de participantes
```

E o laço se encerra, tendo que dar "run" no programa de novo. **Como faço pra manter o laço, para aceitar um novo input mesmo após um erro e lançamento de uma exceção?**

Comment: Olá Marcos. Penso que exceptions/raise não deveria ser usado para informar erros por parte do usuário.

Comment: Entendi, é que sou novo nisso e to aprendendo o que deve ou não ser feito. Vou alterar a exceção, porem o que eu preciso fazer pra manter o laço? Pq mesmo que eu não mostre pro usuário, se informado um valor que não passe na validação, o laço vai ser desfeito. O que você sugere que seja feito?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

por hora como forma de tentar executar mesmo numa passagem de valor inválida eu faria a seguinte mudança:

```
def validando_num_participantes(self):
    try:
        if len(self.participantes) >= self.num_sorteados:
            return True
    except:
        SorteioInvalido(
        'Registre um número de pessoas a serem sorteadas que seja menor ou igual ao número de participantes')
```

Se a exceção estiver ocorrendo aqui os blocos `try:` e `except:` respectivamente tentarão executar a primeira parte e caso não haja como levarão a segunda como uma exceção tratada, e o programa continua seguindo